# Kite experiment

Tags: biographical-details

In Benjamin Franklin's kite given in the link below http://www.benjamin-franklin-history.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Franklins-kite.jpg 
I want to know how electric charge pass through strings as well as sticks both being an insulator after passing through iron?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know how electric charge pass through strings as well as sticks both being an insulator after passing through iron

Good point, remember that water is a conductor of electricity when it has traces of salts and ions. Rain water has enough ions to make it conductive.

If you check Wikipedia, you will see the same question answered.

> According to the 1767 Priestley account, Franklin realized the
>   dangers of using conductive rods and instead used the conductivity of
>   a wet hemp string attached to a kite. This allowed him to stay on the
>   ground while his son assisted him to fly the kite from the shelter of
>   a nearby shed. This enabled Franklin and his son to keep the silk
>   string of the kite dry to insulate them while the hemp string to the
>   kite was allowed to get wet in the rain to provide conductivity. A
>   house key belonging to Benjamin Loxley was attached to the hemp string
>   and connected to a Leyden jar; a silk string was attached to this. "At
>   this key he charged phials, and from the electric fire thus obtained,
>   he kindled spirits, and performed all other electrical experiments
>   which are usually exhibited by an excited globe or tube." The kite was
>   not struck by visible lightning; had it been, Franklin would almost
>   certainly have been killed. However, Franklin did notice that
>   loose threads of the kite string were repelling each other and deduced
>   that the Leyden jar was being charged. He moved his hand near the key
>   and observed an electric spark, proving the electric nature of
>   lightning.